# Triangle inequality of Minkowski functional

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a vector space and $K$ a convex subset of $X$ with $0\in K^0$. Then $$p_K(x+y) \leq p_K(x)+p_K(y) ,\forall x,y\in X$$
My book offers the following proof:

Suppose $s>p_K(x)$ and $t>p_K(y)$. Then $x/s,y/t\in K$ and because K is convex $$\frac{x+y}{s+t}=\frac{s}{s+t}\frac{x}{s}+\frac{t}{s+t}\frac{y}{t}\in K$$
so $p_K(x+y)\leq s+t$. Here is where I stop understanding : This happens $\mathbf{for\ every\  s>p_K(x),t>p_K(y) \implies p_K(x+y) \leq p_K(x)+p_K(y)}$

I can't get the implication that is written in bold letters. Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you may take, for any $\varepsilon>0$,  $s=p_K(x)+\varepsilon/2$ and $t=p_K(y)+\varepsilon/2$. So you have proven that 
$$
p_K(x+y)\leq p_K(x)+p_K(y)+\varepsilon. 
$$
As $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, you get your inequality.

Comment: By arbitrary you mean that we can take it as small as we want? Like, the limit of $ε$ tending to $0$ on both sides, right?

Comment: It's not about limits. If a real number is less than all positive numbers, then it is less than or equal than zero. So if $p_K(x+y)-p_K(x)-p_K(y)<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, then $p_K(x+y)-p_K(x)-p_K(y)\leq0$.

Comment: Well i've never thought about it this way. Thank you very much :)